# How to use DotConnect For PostgreSQL and entity framework code first

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, code-first, ef-postgresql

I am trying to use POstgreSQL database in my project.
I would like to learn code first developement..
I download dotconnect for PostgreSql (trial version) and I added Devart.Data.PostgreSql dll to my references. Then, I added those lines in my app.copnfig

```
 <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SchoolDBConnectionString" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port = 5432;Database=MyDataBase;user Id=postgres;password=*****" providerName="Devart.Data.PostgreSql" />
    </connectionStrings>
<system.data> 
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="Devart.Data.PostgreSql" />
        <add name="dotConnect for PostgreSQL" invariant="Devart.Data.PostgreSql" description="Devart dotConnect for PostgreSQL" type="Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlProviderFactory, Devart.Data.PostgreSql, Version= 6.8.333.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

WHen I execute my application i have this exeption :

An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.

Comment: Please post here your call stack with the inner exception. If possible, send us a small test project so that we can reproduce the issue in our environment: http://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html .

Comment: Thank you. I have sent a small test project. I need a solution.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to your problem with DevArt ? I'm having the same issue and can't get any feedback from them ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this (Not tested)

```
<provider invariantName="Devart.Data.PostgreSql" type="Devart.Data.PostgreSql.Entity.PgSqlEntityProviderServices,
Devart.Data.PostgreSql.Entity, Version=7.1.26.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
```

and

```
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Devart.Data.PostgreSql" type="Devart.Data.PostgreSql.Entity.PgSqlEntityProviderServices,
      Devart.Data.PostgreSql.Entity, Version=7.1.26.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

---

**Note**: Replace 7.1.26.6 with the actual assembly version.